# Getting 403 unauthorized error access the queue storage from our azure function app

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-functions

[image]

We have three major components at play here

**Function App – 1 (Subscription: 01)**

- Triggered by BLOB (1)
- Writes to Queue (2)

Issue:
Host start up fails.

We observed that the function app is connecting successfully to the BLOB (1)
However, the function app is trying to connect to the Queue within its own storage account ( - bottom left green in the diagram) instead of connecting to the storage account ( - top green) during the flow (2)

This fails with unauthorized access – 403

Related Configuration:
AzureWebJobsStorage
@Microsoft.KeyVault(SecretUri=https://keyname.vault.azure.net/secrets/FunctionStorageSecretUrl)

WEBSITE_CONTENTAZUREFILECONNECTIONSTRING
DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=xxxxxxx

LomStorageBlob:serviceUri
https://xxxxx.blob.core.windows.net

LomContainerPath
xxxxxx

LomStorageQueue:serviceUri
https://xxxxx.queue.core.windows.net

QueueName: xxxxx

**Function App – 2 (Subscription: 01)**

- Triggered by Queue
- Writes to Queue

Host start up is successful.
We can observe connectivity being established to queues in the log.

AzureWebJobsStorage
@Microsoft.KeyVaultxxxxx

WEBSITE_CONTENTAZUREFILECONNECTIONSTRING
DefaultEndpointsProtocol=xxxx
LomContainerPath
xxxx

StorageQueue:serviceUri
xxxx
RequestQueueName
ResponseQueueName

**Storage Account – st1 (Subscription:01)**

- Hosts the Blob and Queues.
- Built in new subscription; but has private link defined in the subscription 02

2 private endpoints defined for BLOB and QUEUE

- Blob-pe01
- queue-pe01

DNS Configured in  Subscription 02

The exception at play here is

> This request is not authorized to perform this operation.
> RequestId:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
> Time:
> Status: 403 (This request is not authorized to perform this operation.)
> ErrorCode: AuthorizationFailure

Note the call to queue in the local storage account(st2)

Permissions given at the storage account (st1) are below:

Managed Identity1

Roles:

- Storage Blob Data Contributor
- Storage Blob Data Reader
- Storage Queue Data Contributor
- Storage Queue Data Message Processor
- Storage Queue Data Message Sender
- Storage Queue Data Reader

Managed Identity2

- Storage Queue Data Contributor
- Storage Queue Data Message Processor
- Storage Queue Data Message Sender
- Storage Queue Data Reader

Functionapp1

- Storage Blob Data Contributor
- Storage Blob Data Reader
- Storage Queue Data Contributor
- Storage Queue Data Message Processor
- Storage Queue Data Message Sender
- Storage Queue Data Reader

Functionapp2

- Storage Queue Data Contributor
- Storage Queue Data Message Processor
- Storage Queue Data Message Sender
- Storage Queue Data Reader

We tried giving all the above roles and permissions still not working

Answer (score 0):

> Configuration: AzureWebJobsStorage @Microsoft.KeyVault(SecretUri=https://keyname.vault.azure.net/secrets/FunctionStorageSecretUrl)

**`AzureWebJobsStorage`** should contain the Storage Account connection string, not the secret present in the Key Vault in both of the Function Apps you are using.

Coming to the Roles on Azure Resources,

- In Storage Account > Access Control > Storage Blob Data Contributor and Storage Queue Data Contributor roles are enough for reading and writing from and to the Blob Containers and Queues.
- For the Function App > Access Control - Contributor Role.
- For the Managed Identity on Storage Account > Storage Blob Data Contributor and Storage Queue Data Contributor roles are enough

Next is the Networking Part of the Azure Function App deployed to the App Service Plan or Premium Plan with the Storage Account Configuration:

- Storage Account associated with the Azure Function App or any other storage account that works as a Input/Output binding for the Azure Function App (both) should be under the Same VNet Integration.
- Enabled the Private Endpoints for both the Blob and Queue on the Storage Account.
- Storage Account > Networking > Allowed Connections only from the Specific VNet and all resources should be in the same region.
- Allowed my Client IP (Machine IP) Address to the Networking of both Function App and Storage Account.
- Added the IP to the App Setting `WEBSITE_DNS_SERVER`, Value 1 to the `WEBSITE_VNET_ROUTE_ALL`, `WEBSITE_CONTENTOVERVNET` under the Function App Configuration.

Function Code:

```cs
using System.IO;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace Net6FunBtApp01
{
    public class Function1
    {
        [FunctionName("Function1")]
        public static async Task Run([BlobTrigger("devhack/{name}", Connection = "ConnStr")]Stream myBlob, string name, ILogger log,
            [Queue("devqueue", Connection = "ConnStr")] IAsyncCollector<string> queueCollector)
        {
            log.LogInformation($"C# Blob trigger function Processed blob\n Name:{name} \n Size: {myBlob.Length} Bytes");
            await queueCollector.AddAsync(name);
        }
    }
}
```

[image]